# Idea\Pycharm + Scss + LiveEdit - не обновляется сайт в браузере после обновления css файла

Tags: css, intellij-idea, pycharm, scss, compass

Я поставил себе Compass с Foundation 5.
Настроил проект в Компасе, указал путь, куда сохранять css файл (путь, где у меня лежит css Джанго проекта).
Настроил в Idea функцию Live Edit, когда изменяя код в Idea, сразу вижу изменения в браузере.

Но вот проблема - когда я вношу изменения в scss, идет автоматическая генерация нового css, и Idea замену css файла не видит. В итоге нужно либо страницу в браузере ручками обновлять, либо заходить в Idea в css файл и делать какое либо изменение (символ добавить\убрать к примеру), чтоб Live Edit увидел работу с файлом и соответственно обновил автоматически страницу в браузере.

Пробовал настраивать генерацию нового css файла после правок scss файла и через compass watch и через встроенную функцию самой Idea (Settings -> Tools -> File Watchers), функция Live Edit не работает в обеих случаях.

Может кто-то сталкивался с данной проблемой и знает, как заставить Live Edit видеть обновление css файла, а не только содержания файла, и соответственно автоматически обновлять страницу в браузере?